# asp .net Validation not working in IE 10

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

Has anyone come across this issue?  I have required field validation on a form that I have tested and know works in IE 7-9, Firefox and Chrome but in IE 10 it allows the form to submit without doing any validation.  The site is in .Net 3.5.  I have done some research online but I can't find anything about this.

Comment: Most probably http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2608565 I will post this as an answer if you confirm it solves the issue for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably support.microsoft.com/kb/2608565.

Which means that your old browser capabilities settings incorrectly recognize ie10 as a browser which doesn't support javascript (which of course is not true). The updated browser capabilities file corrects this problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out a way around it.  I had tried the hotfix and that didn't fix it but I added in Page.IsValid to the submit and it works fine now.  I didn't think this would matter since validation is normally client side only but it seemed to do the trick.

Edit:  I originally used an incorrect hotfix as mentioned support.microsoft.com/kb/2608565 will fix this issue.  Also as mentioned I should always have the Page.IsValid in my submits in case javascript is turned off.

Comment: It does matter, because the client can turn off JavaScript = no validation for you.

Comment: That is why I still think your asp.net incorrectly recognizes your browser caps and renders javascript-free version of the page.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I never thought about that.  I will keep that in mind from now on thanks!

Comment: @WiktorZychla - I think I actually had a different fix I used before.  Which is why it still wasn't working.  I will update my answer.  If you post the link as an answer I will mark it as the correct answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can help out.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientTarget = "uplevel";
    }
```