# RequiredFieldValidator client side validations do not work on IE 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-2.0, internet-explorer-10

All my webforms using RequiredFieldValidator, RegularExpressionValidator and ValidationSummary are not working on IE 10. It is working fine on any other browsers. It is strangely doing postback which does not happen on any other browsers.

Another strange thing is when I open developer console(F12), it seems to be working but it is still doing postback. All these Validations should occur at client side by default.

Has anyone here faced similar problem?

Comment: it should not be any IE 10 problem. Look for java-script error in the debugger of IE.

Comment: There should be javascript error

Comment: I opened developer console, go to script tab and started "debugging", no javascript error comes up. I would say something is wrong with javascript error if it happens on only one page of one website but it is happening across all the pages that use asp:Validator controls.

Comment: TRY BY SETING VALDIATION GROUP.....

Comment: In IE10, I get a DOCTYPE error, which may be due to the blank line preceeding it. Probably more relevant, in IE10, the HTML for the errors that you want to appear do not exist while they do exist in Chrome.

Comment: IE10 is not downloading the related JavaScript. For example, Chrome gets a page that includes a script named WebResource.axd, which actually contains the validation logic, but IE10 is not told to download that file, which is why the `onclick="if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') Page_ClientValidate('');"` ignores it, because the answer to that conditional is `false`.

Comment: I tried to change all DOCTYPEs from http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html. None of them solved this problem. I wanted to know page_ClientValidate too by alert(typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function');, it shows "true" in IE 10.

Comment: DOCTYPE is definitely unrelated after noticing that the browser is not even told to download the `WebResource` file; I was guessing as it was the first error in my console from your page in IE10 (still something you probably want to fix). Definitely a server issue as the answer below eludes.  Typing in `typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function'` in my IE10 console prints `false` from your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745658/asp-net-validation-not-working-in-ie-10) and [link2](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx)

**Edit:**

I got this fix from.. [Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx)

Browser Definition files shipped with .Net 2.0 and .Net 4.0 contains defintions for certain range of browser versions. By default, ASP.NET uses sniffing technology for the user agent string to detect browsers. The browser definition files cover a certain range of browser versions.As the version numbers increase, ASP.NET might not recognize new versions of a browser by using the user agent string. In this case, ASP.NET might handle these versions as an unknown browser and causes inconvenience.

**FIX**

The fix is to get updated browser-definition files.
You can install a machine-wide fix or just fix individual projects.
Hotfixes are availble with download links.
- [.Net 4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088)
- [.Net 2.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100)

Comment: Thank you for those info Nag. I added App_Browser folder to website folder since IE 10 came out so that the server recognises IE 10. I have already done link1 solution. Withk link2, our sites are running on .net 2.0 and depending on some DLL files which do not work well with later versions of .net 2.0. I will try with .net 3.5 and IE 10 on a new website.

Comment: no up votes... Please post the result after your trails with the next versions of .net 2.0

Comment: @Nag You should transfer some of the linked knowledge to your answer. Answers that only contain links break after their links do (obviously less of a problem with MS KB, but even they move links around sometimes).

Comment: Hey mate, thank you for that. I finally got it working from your link2 .net 20.  Specifically from http://nuget.org/packages/App_BrowsersUpdate.net20. Could you please update your answer as pickypg suggested? I will accept your answer.