# javascript validation not firing on IE10 but working on all other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, internet-explorer-10

I have a hidden page element on my form with an id called **remainingpoints**. I also have the following javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#FileSubmit").click(function (event) {

    var remainingpoints = document.getElementById("remainingpoints").value;

    if (parseInt(remainingpoints) == 0)
            alertString += "PARTICIPATION POINTS: You have already assigned your course quota\nof " + '@Model.Course.ParticipationPoints' + " participation points to this course, you cannot add further\ncontent without making amendments"
        else if (parseInt(contentpointsvalue) > parseInt(remainingpoints))
        {
            alertString += "PARTICIPATION POINTS: You already have " + '@Model.CoursePointsToDate' + "/" + '@Model.Course.ParticipationPoints' + " points assigned to this course, you can only add a maximum of " + '@Model.CoursePointsRemaining' + " more but this video\n has a participation value already assigned for " + contentpointsvalue + " points which would \nexceed the total value allocated to the course"
        }
    });
});
```

Validation is being fired on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari but for some reason the client side validation does not work on IE10. Can anyone see why this may be?

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: What is `contentpointsvalue`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917503/requiredfieldvalidator-client-side-validations-do-not-work-on-ie-10

Comment: contentpointsvalue is another field which i have ommitted for brevity, it is just a number value also and no errors are being displayed in console